# Compass ellipsis syntax

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass, sass

I feel like an idiot but I really cannot figure this out.

I'm using [John Long](https://github.com/jlong)'s Sass Twitter Bootstrap conversion of the regular Twitter Bootstrap items. Located here on [GitHub](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap)

Whenever I compile it I get the following error:

```
    error sass/bootstrap.scss (Line 246 of sass/bootstrap/_mixins.scss: Invalid
CSS after "...-shadow($shadow": expected ")", was "...) { ")
Sass::SyntaxError on line ["246"] of C: Invalid CSS after "...-shadow($shadow":
expected ")", was "...) { "
```

Here is the syntax that it complains about:

```
// Drop shadows
@mixin box-shadow($shadow...) { 
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadow;
     -moz-box-shadow: $shadow;
          box-shadow: $shadow;
}
```

I've never seen that syntax before with the ellipsis on a mixin.

My question is how do I fix this error. It's clearly a problem I have.

I'm using Compass v0.12.2

Comment: If you aren't too invested in using that particular version of SASS bootstrap, there is another version I use that I've never had issues compiling.

Github link [here](https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: @Darrrrrren The reason I with with jLong's is that it is very active and I usually dont have to wait long to update (no pun intended) :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the syntax for variable arguments: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments

You will need to upgrade Sass, since it is a new feature of 3.2x.

Comment: You are correct! I updated Compass and not Sass.. oops :) Thanks though

Comment: There is a question on how to update: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92468/how-do-i-update-to-the-latest-version-of-sass/278462#278462

Answer (score 1):

Look like you have to update sass gem , try this line (I'm assuming you have gem installed)

```
 gem update sass
```